# Why is this NULL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nslog

Can anyone tell me why this is NULL ?

So Array1 is NSMutable, and has an NSString object "UserName" at index 0;

```
NSLog (@"Contents of array1 %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:0]); //prints UserName
```

Now , I do this...

array2 belongs to another class. I reference the class, import .h file, and add property and synthesize it.

```
[object2.array2  addObject: array1]; //array2 is NSMutable properly initialized in it's respective class in the init method

NSLog (@"Contents of array2 %@", [object2.array2 objectAtIndex:0]); //prints (null)

tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tempArray = [object2.array2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"%@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:0]); // Prints (null) // Should be UserName
```

***Adding more information:***

`object2` is an object of another class (which is a subclass of `NSObject`), and object2 contains array2 as it's `property`.

object2 is nil. WHY ? HOW ??

Comment: `array2` and `Array2`? I have a feeling you're not posting your real code...

Comment: Can you show the initialization of `array2`? also, it's probably a typo but in one place you're writing `array2` and in another `Array2`.

Comment: first of all, you probably want to do [array2 addAllObjects: array1] or similar. what you are doing is adding an NSMutableArray to array1, not the UserData string.

Comment: Have you initialized `array2`?

Comment: Mr. @godexsoft. I intend to add an NSMutableArray as an object of another array

Comment: Ok now I see your point. sorry for misunderstanding your code :)

Comment: Is there any chance your code snippets are on different threads or something? I never seen code like this failing except in threaded code.

Comment: @godex: Nope. It is exactly as it is typed above. Simple and easy. but NULL

Comment: btw, with your new code: object2.array2, how is that initialized? self.array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithSize:1] or array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithSize:1]; ?

Comment: Like this - NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.array2 = array;
        [array release];

Comment: @Legolas you should not release it.

Comment: @WTP: I am releasing a Temporary array.

Comment: @WTP, he can release it "if he is retaining it via its property".

Comment: @Legolas that is a very strange way to init your array. try doing self.array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithSize:1]; instead and try your other code as is. I will be surprised if that fails.

Comment: Did you mean [arrayWithCapacity:1] ? That is also null

Comment: @Legolas yes i meant that. how the hell is that null? jesus.. i'm out of ideas now.

Comment: Why are you creating an array `tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` and then immediately leaking it `tempArray = [object2.array2 objectAtIndex:0];`?

Comment: @John Caswell: But it should work right ?

Comment: @Legolas: "It should work" only in the sense that it's probably not directly related to the problem at hand.

Comment: @John Caswell: Yes ! That is what I had meant.

Comment: Can you show code where you adding object to `array1`?

Comment: .................added more information.

Comment: @jamapag: I believe that would make the question long and might make people lose interest. I want to keep it as simple as possible. I can tell you that if I display array1, it works fine, and it has the object.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Apologies !! Sorry for misspelling you name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog (@"Contents of array2 %@", [object2.array2 objectAtIndex:0]); //prints NULL
```

If that 'prints NULL', then it is for one of four reasons:

- `object2` is nil
- `object2.array2` returns nil
- the object at index 0 is the string "NULL"
- the object at index 0's `description` method returns the string "NULL"

Which is it?

---

> object 2 is nil. I wonder why.

Most likely because you didn't initialize it in the first place.  Show your initialization code and also drop a log statement or breakpoint and make sure it is actually being executed.

Comment: Mr. @bbum: Could you please check the question again ? I have changed NULL to (null). I had used Capitals to emphasize that is was null. (obviously it failed)

Comment: @Legolas: if it's printing `(null)`, then one of the four objects that bbum identified is `nil`.

Comment: I think so too. Could you tell me why it could be nil ?

Comment: @Legolas: The simplest thing to do is log all four of those objects individually at the same point where you're now logging the full expression. Figure out which one is the problem, then trace backwards.